# Making Windows Up/Down Arrows Behave Like OSX

Tags: windows-8, autohotkey

In any text box in OSX, the up and down arrows move the cursor up or down a line, as expected. On the last line, though, pressing the down arrow behaves like the "End" key, moving the cursor to the end of the line. Similarly, on the first line, the up arrow moves the cursor to the beginning of the line.

I've started using Windows 8, in which the up and down arrows still attempt to go up or down a line, regardless of where the cursor is in the document, and I'd like to, if it's possible, make Windows mimic OSX.

My gut tells me that, if this can even be done, it'll probably be through AutoHotKey, but I haven't been able to find a way to identify when I'm at the bottom of a text box. Is there some way to do that? Some other, non-AHK method that would do it?

Comment: Just in case you were unaware: The Windows keyboard shortcut to jump to the end of the last line in text areas is Ctrl-End, and it works from anywhere in the text area.  Conversely, Ctrl-Home takes you to the beginning of the first line.

Comment: @techie007 Thanks! I'm good with those two, just too lazy to reach all the way up to the End key. :)